# how to make copy of custom object to from sandbox to other sandbox

Tags: custom-object, sandbox, change-set, sandbox-clone

I'm trying to make a copy of custom object from a sandbox to other sandbox,
like by using "Change Sets".
However, that was not successfull and I cannot find good ways of doing that.

How can I move custom object to other sandbox environment including existing records?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why weren't you able to move the object using changeset? What error(s) did you get? Like sfdcfox said, you need different tools to move your metadata(objects, fields, etc) and records (dataloader, import wizard, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use changeset or ant migration tool for migrating your objects/fields, once you moved the object/field to the other sandbox. You can move your data using Apex Data Loader or Data Import Wizard,

to use the changeset you have to enable Allow Inbound Changes checkbox in target sandbox see the below screenshot

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use the Apex Data Loader or another tool. Change sets can move objects and fields, but not individual records. There is no direct tool in Salesforce that does this. Another alternative is to run a report, export as a CSV, then import using the Data Import Wizard found in Setup.